# When beer tapping, why does only one of the beers foam up?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

In the paper [Physics of beer tapping](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2678) the author go through an explanation of the phenomenon of beer tapping, i.e. the foaming up of beer in glass bottle after it has been hit at the top of the bottle by another beer.

Why does only the bottle being hit overflow and not the bottle that is being used as the "hammer"?

My guess is that 1) the moving bottle experiences less acceleration in the impact (due to the way it is held) or that the direction of the hit (from above or from below) matters.

Is there some reason that the reflected wave in the lower of the bottles is more "powerful" than the "direct" wave of the upper bottle?

Related questions on stackexchange [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/is-there-more-energy-in-the-collapse-of-a-cavitation-bubble-than-the-energy-requ) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/hit-a-bottle-of-beer-on-the-top-with-another-causes-the-first-to-spit-all-the-ga?lq=1).

Comment: Seems like it does happen to some extent in both bottles, see the demo here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p11X5ueA6Sk but as for any differences between the two bottles, I would venture to guess that it is because the one that is open does not have a hard surface reflecting the pressure wave multiple times see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3747v1.pdf

Comment: I have always attempted this with two open bottles. I see in the video that there is some limited foaming of the "upper" bottle which suggests that it is a quantitative difference not a qualitative difference between the two bottles.

Comment: If I understand the paper correctly, the bottom of the top bottle acts temporarily as a hard surface reflecting the pressure waves in the bottom bottle ("closing" it temporarily) which magnifies the effect in that bottle.

Comment: (Hypothesis) I think it's important to look at the directions of the fluid acceleration relative to each bottle. For the bottom bottle, the bottle is being accelerated *away* from the fluid, requiring very low (negative) pressure in the fluid for a short time in order for the velocities of the bottle and fluid at the boundary to be identical. This low pressure could cause the $CO_2$ to come out of solution during that short period, since gas solubility increases with pressure. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) In the top bottle, the bottle is accelerated *up* into the fluid, causing momentary high pressure in the beer in order to halt the fluid. The $CO_2$ has no reason to come out of solution in this case, so you don't observe the same amount of foaming.